# Increase memory in tweak error

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I was tried to used jetslammed like this in my jailbreak tool, but it is encountered an error that i do not know where it comes from. Anyone take a look please  , this is my code:

```
char *x = (char *)"testoll";
jetslammed_updateWaterMark(1024, x);
```

And this is the errors:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "jetslammed_updateWaterMark(int, char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.mm.f37d78b2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

P/S: I have linked the jetslammed library and include jetslammed.h too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mangling a C symbol as if it were a C++ one. You'll need to include the C header like this:

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <jetslammed.h>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day :D